# im trying to upload multiple images but when I push this code on server it gives me the hashName error

Tags: file-upload, hash, upload, laravel-8, image-upload

im trying to upload multiple images but when I push this code on server it gives me the hashName error.

**This Is the error:**

> Call to a member function hashName() on null

HTML code:

```
<form action="{{ route('products.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Add CSRF Token -->
        @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Name</label>
        <p> le nom du theme <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required></p>
        </br>
        <p>la description du theme<input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" required</p>
       <div class="form-group">
       <input type="file" name="image" required>
       <input type="file" name="image2" required>
       <input type="file" name="image3" required>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prix" required>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nb_download" required>
       <input type="file" name="file" required>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

the route:

```
route::resource('products','App\http\controllers\TemplatesController');
```

templatesController (store function):

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
            
            $templates = new templates([
                "name" => $request->get('name'),
                "description"=>$request->get('description'),
                "image_path"=>$request->image1->hashName(),
                "image_path2"=>$request->image2->hashName(),
                "image_path3"=>$request->image3->hashName(),
                "prix"=>$request->get('prix'),
                "file_path" => $request->file->hashName(),
                "nb_download"=>$request->get('nb_download')
            ]);

            $request->image1->move(public_path('images'));
            $request->image2->move(public_path('images'));
            $request->image3->move(public_path('images'));


            $templates->save(); 
            
        

        return view('products.create');

    }
```

Comment: One of your calls to `hashName()` (e.g. `"image_path"=>$request->image1->hashName()`) is done on a null object. In other words, one of those `$request` fields is returning null in your *templatesController* `new templates` statement. Does it work before you push it live?

Comment: thank you connor, yes it worked! and i don't have any null object. i don't know what the problem !

Comment: You certainly do have a null object or you wouldn't get the error. *"Call to a member function hashName() on null"* means the variable you call `hashName()` on isn't set to an instance. For example if `$request->image1` is null, you can't call `hashName()`. Try logging the value of `$request` to verify it's set to what you think it is. It's probably missing a field value.

Comment: thank you connor it was a typo! the input type name was "image" not "image1".

Answer (score 0):

it was a typo! the input type name was "image" not "image1". –